# How do i draw a semi circle/ oval whose flat side touches the bottom of the screen in compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, android-jetpack-compose

The preview looks like below.. I want the width of it to be half the screen size and height to be 1/20th of the screen height.
I tried

```
Box(
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(
            Color.Gray
        )
) {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        val canvasWidth = size.width
        val canvasHeight = size.height

        drawArc(
            color = Color.Cyan,
            topLeft = Offset(0f, canvasHeight / 2),
            startAngle = 0f,
            sweepAngle = -180f,
            useCenter = false
        )
    }
}
```

I have come this far only.. I want the arrangment to be purely independent of any hardcoded numbers.

[I am trying to create this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsmhX.png)

[And I have come this far only :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xr6x.png)